# getbounds problem with tweenlite

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a bitmapData that I want to scale with TweenLite but when applying
the transformaroundcenter plugin I get this error message:

"Property getBounds not found on flash.display.BitmapData and there is no default value."

Where do I have to place the "activate" line (e.g. into the constructor, other functions, etc.)?

Can anyone help, please? Thanks.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.TransformAroundCenterPlugin;
TweenPlugin.activate([TransformAroundCenterPlugin]);

TweenLite.to(tempScore.bitmapData, 2, {transformAroundCenter: {scale:2}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapData inherits from Object, Bitmap inherits from DisplayObject. Either create a new Bitmap instance from your BitmapData as Peter suggests, or try applying the TweenLite transform to your tempScore object, assuming tempScore is a DisplayObject.

Answer (score 6):

Judging by the exception, it looks like the library/plugin is expecting a `DisplayObject`, which `BitmapData` is not. Try creating a `Bitmap` to pass instead. A `Bitmap` is a `DisplayObject` that represents `BitmapData`.

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tempScore.bitmapData);
TweenLite.to(bitmap, 2, {transformAroundCenter: {scale:2}});
```

Comment: Man that was too early. My fault. Good news is the getBounds error is gone, the bad news is that it throws out the following error messages:"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at com.greensock.plugins::TransformAroundPointPlugin/onInitTween()
 at com.greensock.plugins::TransformAroundCenterPlugin/onInitTween()
 at com.greensock::TweenLite/init()
 at com.greensock::TweenLite/renderTime()
 at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
 at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()"